# OCaml error: "The present constructor Function__webkit_gradient has a conjunctive type"

Tags: ocaml, reason

What this error means and how can i solve it? I am trying to generate types based on the CSS spec at [styled-ppx](https://github.com/davesnx/styled-ppx) and got stuck at this error that i dont know how to it fix neither what that means exactly.

I tried to get OCaml inference from the target file with dune using `(ocamlc_flags -i :standard)` because my suspect is that infered types and generated types are crashing since both are polymorphic variants, but had problems generating targets.

You can check the pull request with the problem being reproducible [here](https://github.com/davesnx/styled-ppx/pull/304)

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. And although links to additional resources are great, the question itself should contain enough information to identify and reproduce the problem. See [ask].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your ppx code,

```
  let mk_typ = (name, types) => {
    let core_type = ptyp_variant(types, Closed, None);
```

it is unlikely that the meaning of `types` matches your expectation.

In this context, the list of type `types` represents an intersection (aka a conjunction) of types.
For instance, in

```ml
type 'a t = [< `A of int & float ] as 'a
```

the `types` list would contain the ast nodes for the type `int` and `float`.
(You can have a look at the latest version of OCaml manual https://ocaml.org/api/compilerlibref/Parsetree.html#TYPErow_field_desc to have more detailed description of those AST nodes.)

You probably meant to box the list of types in a product type

```ml
type t = [ `A of (int * float) ]
```

Indeed, polymorphic variant constructors always have arity one. Otherwise,
`` `A _ * _ `` would not be unifiable with `` `A of _ ``.

Concerning your exact error message, the conjunctive type error that you are half-describing is likely related to the fact that conjunctive (like `int & float`) are only allowed as argument of polymorphic variant constructors in the upper bound of a polymorphic variant type.
In other words,

```ml
type 'a t = [< `A of int & float ] as 'a
```

is fine because we are on the right-hand side of `<`.
But both

```
type 'a t = [> `A of int & float ] as 'a
```

and

```
type t = [ `A of int & float ]
```

yields an error

```
Error: The present constructor A has a conjunctive type
```

because the conjunction of types appears in the lower bound of the type which lists the constructors that were explicitly present.

EDIT: Why are conjunctive types sometimes allowed?

Having conjunctive types makes it possible to use functions that have incoherent interpretation of some constructors.
For instance, I could have a function that works on either
`` `A of int `` or `` `B of float ``

```
let f = function
| `A n -> float_of_int n
| `B f -> f
```

and another function that expects both `` `A `` and `` `B `` to have a float argument

```
let g (`A f | `B f ) = f
```

If I try to apply `f` and `g` on the same argument

```
let h x = f x +. g x
```

I end up in a situation where `h` can be applied to `` `B 0. `` without trouble

```ml
let z = h (`B 0.)
```

but trying to use `h` on `` `A _ `` for any `_` cannot work

```ml
let error = h (`A 0)
```

```
Error: This expression has type [> `A of int ]
       but an expression was expected of type
         [< `A of float & int | `B of float ]
       Types for tag `A are incompatible
```

This is the kind of situation where conjunctive types arise: `h` has type `` [< `B of float | `A of int & float ] -> float ``. Moreover, we can wait to get a concrete argument of the form `` `A of x `` to check if the constructor argument `x` fit in the conjunction of types `int` & `float`. In this specific case, we know that there are no types that are both `int` and `float`, but more complex cases can happen, and delaying the check is a simple way to handle all cases.

Contrarily, when we have a concrete value of type `` [> `A of 'x ] ``, there is no reason to delay this check. Thus it is not possible to construct a positive value that has a conjunctive type in OCaml. Consequently, it forbids the possibility to write types with conjunctive types in a positive position.

Comment: Thanks, @octachron. What are the use cases of conductive types?

Comment: Conjunctive types improve the reusability of some functions, see my edit.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, If you look at polyvariants, compared to variants, brings so many cases to break safety. I feel it's a good thing.